# How to add different values (rows) of a column using while loop seperated by date and username

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, sum

I'm trying to display payment of users separated with date and username `i.e (GROUP BY date, username)`.
This is the database table

```
id | username | income |  date
   |          |        |
1  |   super  |  750   |  2019-09-21
2  |   super  |  750   |  2019-09-21
3  |   super  |   1    |  2019-09-22
4  |   super  |  750   |  2019-09-22
```

This is the code I'm trying

```
$income = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $income += $row['income'];
}
```

This is what I'm getting the output when I'm seeing the records date wise

```
id | username | income |  date
   |          |        |
1  |   super  |  750   |  2019-09-21
2  |   super  |  751   |  2019-09-22
```

And this is what I'm expecting

```
id | username | income |  date
   |          |        |
1  |   super  |  1500  |  2019-09-21
2  |   super  |  751   |  2019-09-22
```

**The second option I'm trying is**

The sql query

```
SELECT id, username, income, COUNT(*) AS total, date FROM payment
GROUP BY date, username
```

php code

```
$income = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $income = $row['income'] * $row['total'];
}
```

And this is what I'm getting

```
id | username | income |  date
   |          |        |
1  |   super  |  1500  |  2019-09-21
2  |   super  |   2    |  2019-09-22
```

I'm expecting

```
id | username | income |  date
   |          |        |
1  |   super  |  1500  |  2019-09-21
2  |   super  |  751   |  2019-09-22
```

In my opinion this problem occurs due to `value 1` in the row but don't know how to fix that.
Any suggestions will be appreciated
**NOTE** **-** The `3rd, 5th, 7th and 10th row` of the column `income` will contain the value `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are grouping it by username and date, you need to add up the incomes for all rows (using `SUM()`)

So the SQL should be something like...

```
SELECT date, username, SUM(income) AS total 
    FROM payment
    GROUP BY date, username
```